# Rename maven-plugin tag to maven-plugin-development

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

The description of [maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-plugin) states that it should be used for plugin development topics. This is not clear from the name alone and is therefore misused.

There are a lot of [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) questions getting the [maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-plugin) tag solely because a plugin is used. I suggest renaming the [maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-plugin) to [maven-plugin-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-plugin-development) to make its use clear.

Comment: Just saw six suggested edits in a row related to users attaching this tag to questions about maven plugins in general. I think the tag is misnamed as it stands.

Comment: It might as well be that there is a need for a general tag specifying questions about a plugin in maven. But as there are already so many plugin specific (eg. `maven-scala-plugin`) tags this seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I support this. I was doing some Maven Plugin development this week and it was practically impossible to use SO for this purpose as this tag is so often misused. I would say that at least 90% of the questions that use this tag are not at all about Maven Plugin development.

Please, please, can one of the moderators [execute a rename](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731) on this tag.